# iOS: Setting attributed text with [self appearance]

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, uiappearance

I am working on a project where the debug is set up so that if your class does not inherit from a particular class then it shows up when the app is run in debug. For example, a normal textfields text will show up yellow with a red background.

So I have a subclass where I am overriding the initialise method so that I can create a new button. In this class I am setting the title colour and font. However I would also like to set the attributed string so that when someone creates the button the text is always underlined.

I have tried the following code:

```
 + (void)initialize
 {
     [[self appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [[self appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kDOMFontMedium size:12]];

     NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] init];
     NSDictionary *underlineAttribute = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};
attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Privacy Policy"
                                                   attributes:underlineAttribute];

    [[self appearance] setAttributedText:attributedString];

 }
```

However when I run this I get the following: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAppearance setAttributedText:]:`

I can set the underline in code when I use the class. However it seems more logical to have it in the initialise because the text and underline will always be the same.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: The problem is that the title is set on the `UILabel`s button not on button directly and the `attributedText` on `UILabel` doesn't conforms to `UIAppearance ` protocol.  So I don't think is possible to do it with `UIAppearance`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and apologies for the late response. Yeah it seems this is the case.